# How to remove node from parent if touched more than once?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2

I am making a game in which bullets are shot to the bad guy when the button is pressed. I made a function in which whenever it is called it adds more bad guys.

Here is the code: (This method is called multiple times)

```
 func BadGuyPosition()
    let BadGuyCircle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "CircleBadGuy")
    BadGuyCircle.zPosition = 1
    //var mininmum = self.size.width / 600
    let TooMuch = self.size.height - 60

    let PointToShow = UInt32(TooMuch)

    BadGuyCircle.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) + 20 , CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(PointToShow) ))

    let action2 = SKAction.moveToX(-100, duration: 5.0)
    let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()

    BadGuyCircle.runAction(SKAction.sequence([action2,remove]))

    //Physics BadGuy
    BadGuyCircle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: BadGuyCircle.size)
    BadGuyCircle.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Numbering.Badguy
    BadGuyCircle.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = Numbering.Laser
    BadGuyCircle.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    BadGuyCircle.physicsBody?.dynamic = true

    self.addChild(BadGuyCircle)
```

I want it so that the bad guy is removed from the parent if 2 bullets are made in contact with the bad guy.

I got it so that when 1 bullet makes contact with the enemy, it is removed from the parent.  (here is the code)

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let A : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyA
    let B : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB

    if (A.categoryBitMask == Numbering.Badguy) && (B.categoryBitMask == Numbering.Laser) || (A.categoryBitMask == Numbering.Laser) && (B.categoryBitMask == Numbering.Badguy)
    {

        runAction(BadGuyLostSound)
        bulletsTouchedBadGuy(A.node as! SKSpriteNode, Laser: B.node as! SKSpriteNode)

    }









}

func bulletsTouchedBadGuy(BadGuy: SKSpriteNode, Laser: SKSpriteNode){

    Laser.removeFromParent()
    BadGuy.removeFromParent()


}
```

Can Anyone Please Tell me how can I make so that it would take more than one bullet to make the enemy be removed from parent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to remove your collided nodes is using the method `didFinishUpdate`, if you remove or launch a method to remove your node from `didBeginContact` your game could crash searching a collided node that meanwhile is in the process of being removed..

```
class BadGuy: SKSpriteNode {
   var badGuyBulletCollisionsCounter: Int = 0
   init() {
       let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "CircleBadGuy")
       super.init(texture: texture, color: nil, size: texture.size())
       ...
       // fill this part with your BadGuy code
   }
   required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
   }  
}
```

Declare a global var :

```
var nodesToRemove = [SKNode]()
```

In the `didBeginContact` method:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let A : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyA
    let B : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB
    if (A.categoryBitMask == Numbering.Badguy) && (B.categoryBitMask == Numbering.Laser) || (A.categoryBitMask == Numbering.Laser) && (B.categoryBitMask == Numbering.Badguy)
    {
        badGuy = A.node as! BadGuy
        badGuy.badGuyBulletCollisionsCounter += 1
        runAction(BadGuyLostSound)
        bulletsTouchedBadGuy(badGuy, Laser: B.node as! SKSpriteNode)
    }
}
```

In the `bulletsTouchedBadGuy` method :

```
func bulletsTouchedBadGuy(badGuy: BadGuy, laser: SKSpriteNode){
    nodesToRemove.append(laser)
    if badGuy.badGuyBulletCollisionsCounter == 2 {
       nodesToRemove.append(badGuy)
    }   
}
```

Finally:

```
override func didFinishUpdate() 
{   
     nodesToRemove.forEach(){$0.removeFromParent()}   
     nodesToRemove = [SKNode]()
}
```

Comment: Alessandro - I tried really hard to generate a crash by removing a node in didBeginContact, but failed. Have you ever seen this happen?

Comment: Few times but it happened, and I'm not happy in past because my game was in the Apple store with this bug..didBeginContact can be called many times so it's not the right place to remove nodes.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for answering the question , Does the class BadGuy: SKSpriteNode have to be inside the class I am currently working on or do I have to make another swift file ? if not can you tell me where does it go ? ThankYou

Comment: i am asking because badGuypostion method is being called every 0.5 seconds using the NSTimer Scheduled Timer

Comment: You can make all in the same file, the BadGuy class above your class

Comment: Would the rest of the methods above go in the class I already have or in the BadGuy Class ? also how would these variables and methods be used in both classes ?  Thank You

Comment: If you class is too long make a new file. You must thinking about what BadGuy must do and what the game should doing. So when you have a property with BadGuy class type, this is the badguy and the method I can call with him are part of him,shooting,die,jumping..

Comment: Hello... I added the code but the bad guy does not appear on screen

Comment: Have you forgot to addChild your BadGuy node?

Comment: Hello... got everything done like how you said... but for some reason the badGuyBulletCollisionCounter is not increasing whenever the bullet and the enemy touch.... Do you know why is this ?

Comment: I know this because i printed the the counter whenever the bullet and enemy collided

Answer (score 0):

Use the nodes' userData to track it's hit status. When the bullet hits BadGuy, check the nodes' userData to see if it has been hit already. If it has, remove it; if not, indicate that it has  :

```
//Add this when creating BadGuy:
BagGuy.userData = ["HasBeenHit" : false]

    func bulletsTouchedBadGuy(BadGuy: SKSpriteNode, Laser: SKSpriteNode){

        Laser.removeFromParent()

        if BadGuy.userData["HasBeenHit"] == true {
           BadGuy.removeFromParent()
        } else {
           BadGuy.userData["HasBeenHit"] = true
        }
```

or even:

```
        if BadGuy.userData["HasBeenHit"] == true ? BadGuy.removeFromParent() : BadGuy.userData["HasBeenHit"] = true
```

If you want to move the `removeFromParent()` to `didFinishUpdate()` , then simply change the action as follows:

```
        if BadGuy.userData["HasBeenHit"] == true {
           BadGuy.userData["HasBeenHitTwice"]
        } else {
           BadGuy.userData["HasBeenHit"] = true
        }
```

and then in `didFinishUpdate()` remove all nodes with this value set, or construct an array of nodes to be removed as per the other answer.